# How do I erase "writing" from an object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photoshop-effects

I have a picture that has writing over an umbrella:

[image: pic]

I would like to accurately remove the writing from the umbrella so it appears air asia was never there.

What is the most accurate way of doing so? clone tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's numerous ways you could go about doing it; the clone tool is certainly a valid method.

It also depends on what version of Photoshop you have as the later versions may be better at filling it than the earlier versions (such as having content-aware filling)

I user Photoshop CS5, and here's how I'd do it:

I just used the magic wand and a quick content-aware fill and was returned with this result:
[image]

As you can see, after the first time it did a great job filling in most of it. It did a pretty decent job. Now I can come in and either try and refine that content-aware fill or manually patch it up with the clone tool.

I decided to use the lasso tool and use content-aware fill in smaller areas at a time. This is what I got:
[image]

As you can see, it's a lot better, but it still needs some small work. At this point I'd stop using the content-aware fill because by the very edges it starts losing its accuracy. I would just use the clone tool at this point. Hope that helped a bit!